# Print screen and Save in Android

Tags: android

I have an activity for print screen and save to gallery, it works for Android OS 5 (Lollipop) and earlier.
why for OS android 6 and above this code does not work.
please help, and thanks before.

this is my activity :

```
private ImageView imgSS;

View view;
Bitmap bitmap;
ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrayoutputstream;
File file;
FileOutputStream fileoutputstream;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tes_screenshot);

    bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //main = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    imgSS = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgSS);
    Button btnSS = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSS);
    btnSS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View OnclickView){
            view = OnclickView.getRootView();
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
            view.buildDrawingCache(true);
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            imgSS.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));

            //Save bitmap
            String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "//";
            String fileName = "tes.jpg";
            File myPath = new File(extr, fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Screen", "screen");
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the error which is showing.

Comment: probably because of the change in android's permission scheme, where you need the user to allow your app to take screenshots

Comment: @am05mhz Not the way he's doing it-  he's just saving the drawing cache of his root view.  THere's no problem using that method of getting a screenshot.  What he is having problems with is writing it to external storage without the runtime permission

Comment: yes, thanks all, i add the permission and done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it works for Android OS 5 (Lolipop) and earlier. why for OS android 6 and above this code does not work

OS android 6 and above you need to ask [run time permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) because **Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app**

sample code to how to ask runtime permission

```
String permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
){
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]
                        {permission},123);

}
```

here is the [good tutorial for run time permission](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/)

here is the [Android run-time permissions Library](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions)

Comment: yes, i add the permission and solved. thanks @Nilesh

Answer (score 1):

What is the target version of your app ?

If the target version of your app is 6 or above, all the permissions required for your app will be disabled and during runtime you have to request for the permission and once the user says allow, then only you can proceed with the operation.

In your code you are writing and saving the file in externals folder, so you need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Please refer this blog for implementing the runtime permissions in android : 
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/

If you are using Xamarin then refer :
https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/